# Calculating a sum which includes binomial coeffeicients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, wolfram-alpha, gap, calculator

Some formula for calculating the probablity that the difference between the number $6$ and the average of accidentally selected $100$ points among $10000$ points which are distributed in the interval $[2,8]$ with equal distances, is not more than $0.05$; lead to this sum:

$$\sum_{r=493701}^{506199}\sum_{k=0}^{100}(-1)^k\frac{\binom{100}{k}\binom{r-10001k+99}{99}}{\binom{r+99}{r}}$$

It seems that if $r-10001k+99$ is negative then $\binom{r-10001k+99}{99}$ is to be considered zero. btw, it may not be important if there is a calculator or a way that can deal with the sum; then I will correct the details. I tried to calculate it in [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BSum%5B%28%28-1%29%5Ek%29*Binomial%5B100%2Ck%5D*Binomial%5Br-10001*k%2B99%2C99%5D%2FBinomial%5Br%2B99%2Cr%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C100%7D%5D%2C%7Br%2C493701%2C506199%7D%5D) with this command:

```
Sum[Sum[((-1)^k)*Binomial[100,k]*Binomial[r-10001*k+99,99]/Binomial[r+99,r],{k,1,100}],{r,493701,506199}]
```

But it didn't show me any result. Online [Sage](http://cloud.sagemath.com/) seems to be out of access for my internet connection. Is there any other way to calculate or estimate the result of these iterated sums?

Also I tested gap with:

```
sign:= function(n)         
        if n < 0 then
           return 0;
        elif n = 0 then
           return 0;
        else
           return 1;
        fi;
    end;

 Sum([493701..506199],r->Sum([0..100],k->((-1)^k)*Binomial(100,k)*Binomial(r-10001*k+99,99)*sign(r-10001*k+99)/Binomial(r+99,r)));
```

and the result:

```
<integer 714...349 (28661 digits)>/<integer 547...000 (28670 digits)>
```

---

**Edit:** Clément Guérin's answer suggests to write:

$$\sum_{r=493701}^{506199}\sum_{k=0}^{100}(-1)^k\frac{\binom{100}{k}\binom{r-10001k+99}{99}}{\binom{r+99}{r}}
= \sum_{k=0}^{100}(-1)^k\binom{100}{k}\sum_{r=493701}^{506199}\frac{\binom{r-10001k+99}{99}}{\binom{r+99}{r}}
= \sum_{k=0}^{100}(-1)^k\binom{100}{k}\sum_{r=493701}^{506199}\prod_{s=1}^{99}\left(1-\frac{10001k}{r+s} \right)
$$
But I couldn't give this to Wolfram. In fact, one should calculate
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{100}(-1)^k\binom{100}{k}\sum_{r=493701}^{506199}\prod_{s=1}^{99}\left(1-\frac{10001k}{r+s} \right)\frac{sgn(r-10001k+99)+1}{2}.$$

Comment: I am very curious to see the problem that led to this answer. Can you post the same here too? Also, wondering whether the limits of sum over the values of variable $r$ were supposed to be symmetric about the $500000$ value, in which case, the lower limit of the sum should be $493801$ instead of $493701$

Comment: With "numerators" that big, I'd go with Sterling's approximation, to approximate. It's still a huge sum ... I'd also like to know where this came from.

Comment: @DeepakGupta: No the limits are correct. The problem is about the probablity that the difference between 6 and the average of accidentally selected 100 points among 10000 points which are distributed in the interval $[2,8]$   with equal distances, is not more than 0.05.

Comment: @user795571: Then you can directly approximate the original problem by approximating the distribution of that sum by a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Also, Sage is relatively easy to set up on your own machine -- that doesn't answer the question, but it might help...

Comment: The upper index in the top right binomial coefficient becomes negative. By convention, this coefficient is non-zero, but I suspect that in your case you want this to be zero?

Comment: @joriki Yes. Because it's number of solutions of a Diophantine equation I think I must regard it zero. I don't know how I can give it to wolfram or so.

Comment: GAP returned you the exact value of the answer as a rational. You may use `Float` to get its decimal approximation.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: I tested that but it prints `-nan`.

Comment: I can reproduce `-nan` - will have a look. Anyhow, the result is a valid GAP object - a rational number with numerator and denominator in abbreviated forms. `x>1/10^9;` returns `true` and `x>1/10^8;` returns `false`. One could write a GAP code to get more digits by comparison.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov which code?

Comment: I think the most efficient would be to implement long division. `NumeratorRat`, `DenominatorRat` and `QuotientRemainder` should be useful.

Comment: You may also try [FUtil package by Frank  Lübeck](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Frank.Luebeck/gap/FUtil/index.html), see in particular [this section in its manual](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Frank.Luebeck/gap/FUtil/doc/chap1.html#s2ss0). Note that this package is not redistributed with GAP so you have to install it yourself.

Comment: thanks‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.

Answer (score 1):

First (setting r'=r+99) :

$$\frac{\binom{r-10001k+99}{99}}{\binom{r+99}{r}}=\prod_{i=0}^{98}(1-\frac{10001k}{r'-i})$$

Hence :

$$\frac{\binom{r-10001k+99}{99}}{\binom{r+99}{r}}=1+\sum_{s=1}^{99}(-1)^s\sum_{0\leq i_1<...<i_s\leq 98}\frac{(10001k)^s}{(r'-i_1)...(r'-i_s)}$$

Now your sum is equal to :

$$\sum_{r=493701}^{506199}\sum_{k=0}^{100}(-1)^k\frac{\binom{100}{k}\binom{r-10001k+99}{99}}{\binom{r+99}{r}}=$$

$$\sum_{r=493701}^{506199}\sum_{k=0}^{100}(-1)^k\binom{100}{k}+\sum_{r=493701}^{506199}\sum_{s=1}^{99}(-1)^s\sum_{0\leq i_1<...<i_s\leq 98}\frac{10001^s}{(r'-i_1)...(r'-i_s)}\sum_{k=0}^{100}(-1)^k\binom{100}{k}k^s$$

> Now I claim that for any $s<n$ we have that‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌:
>
> $$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}k^s=0 $$

I won't prove it generally, for $s=0$ this is the binomial formula.

For $s=1$ :

$$\sum_{k=0}^nkx^k\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}=x\times \frac{d}{dx}(x+1)^n=nx(x+1)^{n-1}$$

So this is true. For $s=2$ :

$$\sum_{k=0}^nk^2x^k\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}=x\times \frac{d}{dx}x\times \frac{d}{dx}(x+1)^n=x\frac{d}{dx}nx(x+1)^{n-1}=xn(x+1)^{n-1}+x^2n(n-1)(x+1)^{n-2}$$

And so on...

Finally this gives that the your probability is null(!). Although I cannot se where is the error, I might be wrong (given that you are looking for a probability), anyway I think there is a way here to help you compute the sum.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're applying the conventional definition of binomial coefficients with negative upper index, whereas I suspect that in the question these coefficients are meant to be interpreted as zero. (You may have overlooked that the upper index becomes negative because you dropped one of the zeros in $10001$ in the right-hand sides.)

Comment: I hope I can arrage your calculation and use wolfram again to see if it gives the results.

Comment: @joriki, thanks, that's why, I was wrong

Comment: @user795571, sorry about my mistake, it worked with $1001$...